# How to find a relative path in JavaFX webview

Tags: java, webview, javafx, path

I want to add an image in [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) webview by invoking:

```
webView.getEngine().loadContent("<img src="image.png" />");
```

But I don't get anything. And I don't want to use a method like:

```
getClass().getResource("image")
```

Because it's going to give me the absolute path which I don't need because in my application I'm going to transfer the page generated with the [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) protocol.

Comment: I created a ticket: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/485